How can I keep a light power animation in an action for NLA (Blender 4.0)
I am trying to create a blinking light animation effect to use NLA to intersperse the light randomly through my animation. However following the same steps I have used for other animations --> Dope Sheet / Action Editor the light power value never appears in the action editor and if I push down my action to the NLA timeline and move it around the light does not light.
Is this a known bug or is there some way to make this work?
Thanks
Rich
Here is a link to the Blender file


i just tried it out - it works like every other animation. Pls provide blend file so we can check out what you made wrong, since you didn't showed us any technical settings you made but just described your process very roughly.

Hi, Rich, Thanks to @Chris, this sounds like a side-effect of some other aspect of your set-up, which will be pretty much impossible to trace without your file. Please share a minimal version exhibiting the fault on https://blend-exchange.com/

it won't create an action but if you can push down the animation into the NLA and move the strip so I'm not sure why you say that the light does not light

Hi - I will try again with a new Blender file and if it still doesn't work for me I will upload the file. Thanks.

Okay I added the Blender file. I have screen grabs showing the Action editor adds lines if I animate the location or rotation of the light but not the power.

I did just learn that shift key animations can be stashed as separate NLA.

Yes, the power doesn't appear in the AE.  Why: I don't know and that is indeed odd, even if I disable only show selected.  But POWER appears in many other editors.   I edited your file as follows:

I used the light power panel to insert keyframes for off-on-off animation for one segment of eventual NLA



Use the NLA editor to push-down and create an NLA track for the light power


I can now Duplicate the track and drag/drop wherever I want to cause another light flash.   Note that I can also see Power in the Graph Editor and Dope Sheet.


Thanks so much. I'm glad it wasn't me with the power setting not showing up in the Action Editor.
